# Parallelizing a simple matrix assignment in Python with MPI

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, joblib

I have a rather simple parallelization question that I can't seem to work out.  I had parallelized a simple matrix assignment using joblib in Python which worked nicely on my workstation, but now I need to run the code on a HPC and the as-is code is not playing nicely with MPI.  A skeleton of the code is below (I have stripped out a lot of not-relevant computation).  Basically I have a large matrix that I want to fill in and at each point the value is a sum over many energies and eigenvalues, so this is the 'slow step' of the calculation.  When I run this on my workstation I just parallelize that fill in using `Parallel` and `delayed` from `joblib` but of course when I run this on the cluster using `mpirun --bind-to none -n 16 python KZ_spectral_function.py | tee spectral.out` for example the code runs basically in serial (although with some odd behavior).

So, what I think I need to do is to convert that joblib line over to mpi4py, include an `if rank == 0:` statement encompassing everything in the main function, and just modify the the contents of `gen_spec_func()` and divvy up the calls to `spec_func()` to the different cores.  This is the part where I am stuck, as all the examples I have read that were simple enough for me to understand use some variation of `COMMS.scatter()` and then append the results to a list, as far as I can tell in a random order, and I don't know quite enough to adapt them to something where I want the results to go in a specific place in the matrix.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, as neither parallelization nor python are strengths of mine ...

Code Snippet (simplified):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as lina
import time
from functools import partial
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
    
# Helper Functions
def get_eigenvals(k_cart,cellMap,Hwannier,G):
   ## [....] some linear algebra, not important
   return Ek

def gen_spec_func(eigenvals,Nkpts,Energies,Sigma):
   ## This is really the only part that I care to parallelize
   ## This is the joblib version
   num_cores=16
   tempfunc = partial(spec_func,Energies,Sigma,eigenvals)
   spectral = np.reshape(Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(tempfunc)(i,j) for j in range(0,Nkpts) for i in range(0,len(Energies))),(Nkpts,len(Energies))).T
   return np.matrix(spectral)
  
def spec_func(Energies,Sigma,eigenvals,i,j) :
   return sum([(1.0/( (Energies[i]-val)**2 + (Sigma)**2 )) for val in eigenvals[j,:]])

#--- Start of main script
Tstart = time.time()
# [...] Declare Constants & Parameters
# [...] Read data from disk
# [...] Some calculations on that data we want done in serial

Energies = [Emin + (Emax-Emin)*i/(Nenergies-1) for i in range(0,Nenergies)]
kzs = [kzi+(kzf-kzi)*l/(nkzs-1) for l in range(0,nkzs)]
DomainAvg = np.matrix([[0.0 for j in range(0,Nkpts)] for i in range(0,Nenergies)])
for kz in kzs:
  ## An outer loop over Kz
  print("Starting loop for kz = ",kz)
  # Generate the base k-grid (symmetric)  in 1/A for convenience
  # [...] Generate the appropriate kpoint grid
  for angle in range(0,Nangles): 
     ## Inner loop over rotation angles
     #--- For each angle generate the kpoint grid for that domain
     # [...] Calculate some eigenvalues, small matrices not a big deal, serial fine   
     #--- Now we Generate the spectral function for that grid
     ### Ok, this is the slow part that we want to parallelize
     DomainAvg += gen_spec_func(eigenvals,Nkpts,Energies,Sigma)
     if(angle%20 == 0):
       Tend = time.time()
       print("Completed iteration ", angle, "of ", Nangles, " at T = ", Tend-Tstart)
  # Output the results (one file for each Kz)
  DomainAvg = DomainAvg/Nangles
  outfile = "Spectral"+str(kz)+".txt"
  np.savetxt(outfile, DomainAvg) 
# And we are done
Tend = time.time()
print("Total execution time was :", Tend-Tstart)
```

EDIT: A very very hack solution I came up with was to encode the matrix indices in the matrix itself as floats, then use scatter() and gather() to distribute the matrix, replace the value with the calculation output, and reassemble the matrix.  This is of course not a good idea since it requires int<->float conversion but it was the only way I could come up with that didn't require rebuilding the entire matrix from the gathered data index by index (instead just using hstack() and reshape() to put it together).  I feel like there must be some tool I am missing that assists in distributed calculation for arrays/matrices where the index matters so I would still be interested if someone has a tip/pointer in this regard.

Minimum Working Example:

````
import numpy.linalg as lina
import time
import math
from functools import partial
from mpi4py import MPI
#-- Standard Comms
COMM = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = COMM.Get_size()
rank = COMM.Get_rank()


Nkpts = 3
Energies = [1.00031415926*i for i in range(0,11)]
#--- Now we Generate the spectral function for that grid
# This will be done in parallel using scatter/gather in MPI
if rank == 0:
   # List that we will scatter to the different nodes
   # Encode the matrix index from whcn each element came as a float
   datalist = [float(j+i*Nkpts) for j in range(0,Nkpts) for i in range(0,len(Energies))]
   data = np.array_split(datalist, COMM.Get_size())
else:
    data = None
# Distribute to the different nodes
data = COMM.scatter(data, root=0)
print("I am processor ",rank," and my data is",data)
for index in range(0,len(data)) :
  # Decode the indicies
  j = data[index]%Nkpts
  i = math.floor(data[index]/Nkpts)
  data[index] = 100.100*j+Energies[i]
COMM.Barrier()
dataMPI = COMM.gather(data,root=0)
if(rank==0) :
  spectral = np.reshape(np.hstack(dataMPI),(Nkpts,len(Energies))).T
  spectral_func = np.matrix(spectral)
  print(spectral_func)```
````

Comment: From two seconds of searching it looks like joblib using shared memory paralleism, while MPI is distributed memory. So it is essentially impossible to translate your joblib code into MPI. For MPI you need to give each process its own part of the data. There is no shared data, or a way to have multiple jobs access some shared object.

Comment: Hi Victor,  thank you for your reply; I was not aware of that distinction between the two.  I was able to come up with a very kludge solution using mpi4py where I populated the flattened matrix with its indices (encoded as floats) and then used np.split() and scatter() / gather() to distribute the matrix, replace the float representation of the index with the calculation output, and pass back for reassembly.  It is of course not a very stable solution (as roundoff error begets indexing error) but might work for my primitive application.

Comment: Using a scatter is a popular solution but of course not scalable. The "proper" way to use MPI is to build all data distributed from the start. Just imagine you have 1000 compute nodes; you can never build your matrix in one place. Also doing scatter introduces a sequential bottlenck so your performance will be bad.